# Pls tell the point of inflections of $\arcsin \left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$. Is it having $1$ and $-1$ as point of inflection?

Tags: calculus

Pls tell with apporopriate proof because if we say concavity changes then it will be POI, But also we say tangent is possible at point of inflection, then $1$ and $-1$ will not be pt of inflection.

Comment: The function is not differentiable at $ \ \pm 1 \ \ . $  From the definitions I've seen, those would be points where the concavity changes, but are _not_ regarded as inflection points.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Points $x=0, 1, -1$ are the points where the curve changes convexity.